# Remove two parent divs with jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to do this to remove 2 divs:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.date-outer').removeClass('date-outer').addClass('remove1').unwrap('.remove1');
    $('.date-posts').removeClass('date-posts').addClass('remove2').unwrap('.remove2');
});
```

to remove this:

```html
<div class="Posts">
  <div class="remove1">
    <div class="remove2">
      <div class="keep-This">
        <p>Content</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to SO Eduardo. This is what you want:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".keep-This").unwrap();
    $(".keep-This").unwrap();
});
```

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mjpoo/9w6dfa0j/).

Comment: Or just `$(".keep-This").unwrap().unwrap();`

Comment: Glad to help @eduardosilva. Of course as Rory says you can chain them but I wanted to write it in a way that is easiest to understand. Indeed you could also put it in a loop if you wanted to get even fancier but that is not recommended because we like to keep things simple.

Answer (score 1):

You can rely on pure JS solely.

```
function removeElement(className) {
  const elem = document.getElementsByClassName(className)[0];
  elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
}

removeElement('remove1')
removeElement('remove2')
```

Comment: Why would the OP want to use vanilla JavaScript when they are able to do it easily in their choice of jQuery? Please explain why using JavaScript is better?

Comment: it's bad practice to use jquery, and should not be used post 2020 for sure